# Getting internal server error when executing a cosmos db query from c#

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.1, c#-8.0

Getting internal server error while executing a cosmos db query from c# code.

```
string query = SELECT c.id FROM c JOIN s in c.Names WHERE STARTSWITH(s.text, 'order') OR STARTSWITH('order', s.text)

var result = await documentRepository.GetQueryPageData<MyModel>(containerId, query, searchRequest.PageSize, searchRequest.PageNumber, id);
```

This query is getting executed successfully in cosmos db. issue is happening only when passing keyword **order**
Dotnet Core Version 3.1
c# 8 and VS 2019

Comment: What is the specific content of the exception?

Comment: I have tried with various combinations but cannot reproduce any exceptions. Could you please show us the code for GetQueryPageData and provide a sample document to troubleshoot further.